# VBA: Msgbox Loop that sums values that are between two numbers, inclusive

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA and I'm completely stumped. I have a range of values (sales) in the range `A2:A40`. I need it so that a user is asked to input 2 thresholds, assuming threshold1 <= threshold2. Then have it move down in the list and counts the sales values that are between threshold1 and threshold2, inclusive, displaying the result in a msgbox. Right now when I run the sub the msgbox displays Sales as 0. Any help is appreciated.

```
    Sheet1.Activate
Dim cell As Range
Dim sales As Range
Set sales = Sheet1.Range("B2:B40")
Dim threshold1 As Integer
Dim threshold2 As Integer
Dim sum As Integer
Dim Total As Integer

threshold1 = InputBox("Enter threshold 1", "Threshold 1")
threshold2 = InputBox("Enter threshold 2", "Threshold 2")

For Each cell In sales
    If cell.Value < " & threshold1 & " And cell.Value > " & threshold2 & " Then
        sum = sum + cell.Value
    End If
Next cell

Total = sum

MsgBox "The total sales between " & threshold1 & " and " & threshold2 & " is " & Total & ""
```

Comment: This sounds better suited for a custom `UserForm` than `InputBox` and `MsgBox`.  The UX of 3 separate popups is horrible.

Comment: Or simply use two cells for the inputs and a SUMIFS() for the total.

Comment: your variables threshold1 and threshold2 are integers, you don't surround them with string quotes ("). Get rid of the quotes and remove the & then it will work

Comment: Oh, and you should have some sort of check within your code to ensure threshold1 is greater than threshold2. Something like 'If threshold1 < threshold2 then MsgBox "Enter correct values" Exit Sub End IF'

Comment: And if `threshold1` <= `threshold2` (as stated in the question) you need to change the test to be `If cell.Value >= threshold1 And cell.Value <= threshold2 Then` in order to find the values between those limits.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for what you are trying to do.  However, in your question you said that your values are in Column A, but your sales is set to column B.  The code I have is if your values is in B2:B40. If the values are in A then you will just need to change that.

```
Sub test()

Sheet1.Activate
Dim cell As Range, sales As Range
Dim threshold1 As Integer, threshold2 As Integer, placeHolder As Integer
Dim sum As Integer, Total As Integer

Set sales = Sheet1.Range("B2:B40")

threshold1 = InputBox("Enter threshold 1", "Threshold 1")
threshold2 = InputBox("Enter threshold 2", "Threshold 2")

If threshold1 < threshold2 Then
    placeHolder = threshold1
    threshold1 = threshold2
    threshold2 = placeHolder
End If

For i = 2 To 40
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value < threshold1 And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value > threshold2 Then
        sum = sum + Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
Next i

Total = sum

MsgBox "The total sales between " & threshold1 & " and " & threshold2 & " is " & Total & ""
End Sub
```

Comment: you should add some kind of validation for threshold variables, because if user inputs a value on threshold1 that is greater than threshold2, i think that the sum wont work